# can not Login gpgs when use android 9(level 28) phone. and other version can Login gpgs. please solove this problem

Tags: authentication, google-play-games

i made simple game and connected on gpgs. and tried to test game, almost many android version can run well and Login gpgs well. but some version of android like android 9(level 28) can not login gpgs in game. i tried to find problem, but i can not solve problem.

[com.TheAnd.MatchBlock/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity[12167]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)
2023-06-28 18:00:53.040  3502-3575  WindowManager           system_server                        E  win=Window{c6f2d6f u0 com.TheAnd.MatchBlock/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:871 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:852 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5480 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$01bPtngJg5AqEoOWfW3rWfV7MH4.accept:2 java.util.ArrayList.forEach:1262 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.onAnimationFinished:2408 com.android.server.wm.-$$Lambda$yVRF8YoeNdTa8GR1wDStVsHu8xM.run:2
2023-06-28 18:00:53.788  3233-3305  Netd                    netd                                 E  getNetworkForDns: getNetId from enterpriseCtrl is netid 0[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6CaJ.png)

i tried to find problem from SHA-1 key, but it is worked well. and others methods on internet i searched and used, but can not solve.